# how to delete a recycler view item in sqlite database

Tags: android, kotlin

1)in res a layout with two text view and one button and i want to delete an item of recycler view by clicking on button  can u help me please in adapter the

```
holder.delete.setOnclicklistener{
//                   what to write here

}
```

2) I have written the delete function in sqlite class

3) I have tried everything its not working
4)can anyone tell is the delete function in sqlite correct or wrong

```
class Adapter(var context:Context, data: ArrayList<Subject>):RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>()
{
    lateinit var db:SQHelper

    var data:List<Subject>
    init{
        this.data=data
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layout=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_subject,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(layout)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.title.text=data[position].title
        holder.id.text=data[position].id
        holder.desc.text=data[position].desc
     holder.delete.setOnClickListener {

}

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(item: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item)
    {
        internal var title:TextView
        internal var id:TextView
        internal var desc:TextView
internal var delete:Button
        init {
            title=item.findViewById(R.id.title_textview)
            id=item.findViewById(R.id.id_textview)
            desc=item.findViewById(R.id.desc_textview)
delete=item.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn)
        }

    }

}




//this is adapter
```

```
class SQHelper(context:Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_name,null,1)
{


    companion object{ //place where we can add variables
    val DB_name="subjects.db "
        val TB_name="Subject "
        val id="ID"
        val title ="S_title"
        val desc="S_desc"




    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.execSQL("create table $TB_name(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,S_title TEXT,S_desc TEXT)")//execsql will help to prepare table udsyntax
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db?.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TB_name")
    }
    fun ADD_DATA(title_text:String,desc_text:String){

        val DB=this.writableDatabase
        val values= ContentValues()
        values.put(title,title_text)
        values.put(desc,desc_text)
        DB.insert(TB_name,null,values)

    }
    fun Delete_data(id:String):Int{
       val DB=this.writableDatabase
        val item=DB.delete(TB_name,"id=?", arrayOf(id))
        return item
    }
    val data_getter:Cursor get() {

        val DB=this.writableDatabase
        var data=DB.rawQuery("select * from " + TB_name,null)
        return data
    }


}



//this is sqlite
```

```
this is stack trace
2020-06-10 23:35:32.274 23159-23159/? I/n.myapplicatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-06-10 23:35:32.407 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-06-10 23:35:32.488 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: create CommonDcsHelper
2020-06-10 23:35:32.489 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: cacheJniMembers success
2020-06-10 23:35:32.489 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.489 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.489 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.490 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.490 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2020-06-10 23:35:32.512 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.512 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.512 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.514 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.514 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-06-10 23:35:32.516 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.516 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.516 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.517 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.517 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-06-10 23:35:32.523 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.524 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: constructJavaHashMap: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.524 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: start
2020-06-10 23:35:32.525 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: sendCommonDcs: end
2020-06-10 23:35:32.525 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication W/n.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2020-06-10 23:35:32.598 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-06-10 23:35:32.598 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/MMListParser: onlineVersion -1 defaultVersion 20191101
2020-06-10 23:35:32.599 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/mmscene: open server config failed /data/oppo/multimedia/oppo_display_perf_list.xml
2020-06-10 23:35:32.600 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/mmscene: getHint applicationScene=com.wordsforfun.myapplication,idx=0 none
2020-06-10 23:35:32.617 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/WindowManager: Add to mViews: DecorView@6f4768[add_subject], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@9934781,pkg=com.wordsforfun.myapplication
2020-06-10 23:35:32.683 23159-23192/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : cb65128, I4f6179b11f
    Build Date                       : 08/15/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.26.03.02
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.11.R1.09.00.00.542.031
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2020-06-10 23:35:32.683 23159-23192/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S P 6.0.9 AArch64
2020-06-10 23:35:32.686 23159-23192/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee183, ME: 0x00000000
2020-06-10 23:35:32.700 23159-23192/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-06-10 23:35:32.700 23159-23192/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-06-10 23:35:32.704 23159-23192/com.wordsforfun.myapplication D/mmscene: getHint applicationScene=com.wordsforfun.myapplication,idx=0 none
2020-06-10 23:35:32.711 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 3 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-06-10 23:35:32.761 23159-23159/com.wordsforfun.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

```
//main activity
package com.wordsforfun.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var miscellaneous: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        miscellaneous=findViewById(R.id.miscellaneous)

        miscellaneous.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,option::class.java))
        }

    }
}
```

```
// this is my option class, here in its layout there are two buttons i.e. is add data and saved data .
package com.wordsforfun.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class option : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var add_data:Button
    lateinit var saved_data:Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_option)
        add_data=findViewById(R.id.add_data)
        saved_data=findViewById(R.id.saved_data)
        add_data.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@option,add_subject::class.java))


        }
        saved_data.setOnClickListener {

            startActivity(Intent(this@option,editmiscellenous::class.java))
        }

    }
}
```

```
//this is my subject class 
package com.wordsforfun.myapplication

class Subject (var id:String,var title:String,var desc:String)
```

```
// this is my add_subject class, its layout contains two edit text where i can write something to store it in my editmiiscellaneous class
package com.wordsforfun.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast

class add_subject : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_subject)
        val DB= SQHelper(applicationContext)
        val title_input=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.title_edit_text)
        val desc_input=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.desc_edit_text)
        val add_btn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_btn)
        add_btn.setOnClickListener{
            val title_text=title_input.text.toString().trim()
            val desc_text=desc_input.text.toString().trim()
            DB.ADD_DATA(title_text,desc_text)
            Toast.makeText(this@add_subject,"the subject has been added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startActivity(Intent(this@add_subject, editmiscellenous::class.java))



        }

    }
}
```

```
this is editmiscellaneous class where its layout contains recyclerview and go back button
package com.wordsforfun.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_editmiscellenous.*


class editmiscellenous : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var lists: ArrayList<Subject>
lateinit var DB: SQHelper
lateinit var data:Cursor


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editmiscellenous)


    val go =findViewById<Button>(R.id.go)

    go.setOnClickListener{
        var intent = Intent(this@editmiscellenous,option::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)}
    lists=ArrayList<Subject>()
    DB= SQHelper(applicationContext)
    data=DB.data_getter
    val adapter=Adapter(applicationContext,lists)
    val recycler=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)
    showData()
    list.layoutManager=GridLayoutManager(applicationContext,2)
    list.adapter=adapter


}
fun showData()
{
    if(data.count==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"There is no item",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    while(data.moveToNext()){
        lists.add(Subject(data.getString(0),data.getString(1),data.getString(2)))


    }





}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    showData()
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Use

```
var data:ArrayList<Subject>
```

instead of

```
var data:List<Subject>
```

setOnclicklistener:

```
holder.delete.setOnclicklistener{
   db = SQHelper(context)
   if (db.Delete_data(data[position].id) > 0){
         this.data.removeAt(position)
         this.notifyItemRemoved(position)
   }
}
```

Comment: i did that its working but when i clicked the button the screen flashes and goes to the previous screen can u tell me how to stop that and it gently remains on the same screen or moves to the previous screen gently

Comment: Your app crashed. Look at Logcat and post stack trace

Comment: i am new to android development in logcat there are many options like error ,warn,verbose what is stack trace i don't know and where we have to post it and if i posted in comment, (it is very long)this warning occurs

Comment: and also there was error coming in this line = if (db.Delete_data(data[position].id) > 0) so i wrote if(db.Delete_data(data[position].id.toString().toInt()) then error got over

Comment: You can see the exception. It will be red color.

Comment: means u are saying the exception in that if statement

Comment: the error was"Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Int defined in kotlin.text"

Comment: Could you post part of "Unresolved reference". This is stack trace.

Comment: I am really not understanding what do u want please tell me what do u want

Comment: I am trying to understand the error. If I can't see the error, I can't find a solution

Comment: the error is very long i have sent u all code of my application

Comment: when i saw error there was something which pointed to my adapter that if statement it was"    at com.wordsforfun.myapplication.Adapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(Adapter.kt:39)"

Comment: what is the problem this line =>  if (db.Delete_data(data[position].id) > 0)

Comment: It Is saying that db.delete_data () is unit and i am comparing with 0 an integer so there is red  sign on " >" on this and when I moved the cursor on it it showed the error was"Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Int defined in kotlin.text"

Comment: i am extremely sorry i got my mistake actually i have editted the delete function after posting this question on stack over flow and it is working fine now

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: there is no problem

Comment: hey sorry for late commenting but when i delete the data in random order it is crashing

Comment: what to do now?